# Python - Send a list intro Slack message formatting in Python

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

So I have been playing around with python and Discord's webhook with Slacks message formatting which can be found here: [Slack message formatting](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22username%22%3A%22Google%20website%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22author_name%22%3A%22Google%22%2C%22color%22%3A%22%2300ff00%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%5EPress%20the%20link%20above!%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22www.google.se%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.se%22%7D%5D%7D)

However what I am trying to do is to have a multiply URL that can be sent to slack similar like:

[image]

and now when I have added all my URL to a list and trying to apply it to the formatting etc:

```
{
    "username": "Google website",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "author_name": "Google",
            "color": "#00ff00",
            "text": "^Press the link above!",
            "title": "www.google.se",
            "title_link": URLLIST
        }
    ]
}
```

It tells me that "Must be str, not a list"

And I have been stuck on this since there is not pretty good documentation about this, Anyone that could know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are getting the error, because your `URLLIST` is not a string.

Here are two solution that will work:

Either you do multiple attachments, where every attachment is one link. Then `title_link` must be a URL string, not a list.

Example:

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",            
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/"            
        },
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",            
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/"            
        },
        {
            "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",            
            "title": "Slack API Documentation",
            "title_link": "https://api.slack.com/"            
        }
    ]
}
```

[Message Builder Example](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Slack%20API%20Documentation%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2F%22%7D%2C%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Slack%20API%20Documentation%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2F%22%7D%2C%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Required%20plain-text%20summary%20of%20the%20attachment.%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Slack%20API%20Documentation%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fapi.slack.com%2F%22%7D%5D%7D)

Or you just explode your URL list into a text string (which I would do). Then you do not even need attachments.

Example:

```
{
    "text": "<https://www.google.com|8>\n<https://www.google.com|9>\n<https://www.google.com|10>\n"
}
```

[Message Builder Example](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%7C8%3E%5Cn%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%7C9%3E%5Cn%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%7C10%3E%5Cn%22%7D)